Dojo Database Records/Memory Exceeded
While the existing Dojo code with which I'm working properly processes database records there seems to be a maximum number of records or memory. Beyond this (default?) amount it fails.
In trying to familiarize myself with Dojo I don't see what this value might be, or if there's a way to expand the memory/number of records that can be in the mix? Or is there some other option to address large records?
I believe the following snippet provides insight into the related code:
xhr("viewTrackHistory/getRecords", {
    handleAs: "json",
    preventCache: true,
    query: {current: true, 
        complete: false}
}).then(function(data){ 
    if(data!=null && data.message!=undefined){
        alert(data.message);
    }else{
        rpStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: new Memory({data:data})});
        //Create the grid for the data
        rpGrid = new EnhancedGrid({
            noDataMessage: "No open records were returned in the query.",
            store: rpStore,
            structure: gridStructure,
            plugins:{
                filter: {
                    ruleCount: 5,
                    itemsName: "Records"
                },
                exporter : true
            }
        }, "rpGrid");
        rpGrid.startup();
        dom.byId("loadingOverlay1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        on(rpGrid, "rowClick", function(){
            getInfo(rpGrid);
        });
    }
}

Thanks for any insight.
